# Why is there idlelib.sys

Tags: python, import, python-2.7, python-2.x

what I do is the following:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.modules['idlelib.sys']
None
>>> 'idlelib.sys' in sys.modules
True
```

Why is there this empty module?

Comment: I don't know, but there are many more of these:

    for name, module in sys.modules.iteritems():
        if not module:
            print(name)

You'll see many more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it marks a module load cache miss, see [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2001-April/014136.html).